# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState

Tags: java, selenium

After updating to selenium 3.6 with below details getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V error . Adding Stack Trace for the same. Looks like some issue with Guava version so tried with Guava 20,21,22,23.
Ubuntu version 14.04
google chrome version : 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)
Selenium Version - 3.6.0
Gecko Driver Version:0.19.0
Guava Version :22.0
Chrome Driver Version: 3.6.0
Firefox Browser Version : 55.0.2 (64-bit)
Java8FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeTestjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Vat org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:157)at com.snapdeal.payments.qe.checkout.configuration.DriverFactory.setDriver(DriverFactory.java:230)at com.snapdeal.payments.qe.checkout.configuration.DriverFactory.setDriver(DriverFactory.java:177)at com.snapdeal.payments.qe.checkout.utils.TestBase.beforeTest(TestBase.java:437)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:599)at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have forgot to Change the Version of one dependency

Comment: which dependency you are talking about

Comment: What is this output? Chrome Driver Version: 3.6.0 is strange, the latest version is the v2.33: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt

Comment: so i was using 3.6.0 in my maven dependency but referring v2.33 from my local in my code . I have removed maven dependency and now referring v2.33 only from my local box. but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From your output you are trying to use:

**`Chrome Driver Version: 3.6.0`**

The latest release, now, is the [ChromeDriver 2.33](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: I was using 3.6.0 in my maven dependency but referring v2.33 from my local in my code . I have removed maven dependency and now referring v2.33 only from my local box. but still same issue

Comment: @user2614505 could you share your .pom? anyway, try with the current latest release of guava https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v23.2

Comment: please find the link for the pom.xml       https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QzWvCLqAVEqja69VJVnBQ03fd_ZTWAg2_mkTMfGJ-Zs/edit?usp=sharing